# Calculation of Night shift hours

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with an issue, I have to create an attendance system where I have an employee id and punching time.

There can be multiple punches in a day. So firstly for night shift employees I can't determine his actual in and out time and thus not the duration too.

For example a person came office at 11 pm on 1st April and left at 4 am on 2nd April. In between he also went out for dinner or tea .

I don't have a fixed number of punches. And I need to handle 2 dates as well. So min and max logic wont work.

The major problem is there are multiple punch-ins and row_number wont work as punches are of 2 different dates in case of night shift.

[image: Image1]

here tktno is employeeID , date is the punching time and sno, is number of punches in a day. I have sent you a sample data of a night shift employee.

I require data in given below format -
[image: Image2]

But here as you can see the hours calculation is not correct . I want to correct it .

Comment: Can you include all relevant code in the question? Images are not showing.

Comment: add the query where are you facing the trouble?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Comment: Don't you have a specified start time for the night shift?

Comment: No we don't have specific start time for night shift, the problem is we have multiple punches, not showing which is in and which is out, and i cant use min and max s. no selection because it is of a particular date only.

Comment: @Alexei ,@prabhat The code I have used is not considering the night shifts. and for this i am unable to understand the logic to apply.

Comment: what exactly is attendance id? is it coming from any other table?

Comment: It is an identity column , just to maintain unique records. Its primary key of this table

Comment: ok, thanks, Also can we safely assume a certain gap in punches as end of shift, like 8 hours or so?

Comment: yes u can , there must surely be a gap in 2 shifts.

Comment: Please can you supply a concrete example and explain the logic of how you  decide how long the shift is. It isn't clear from your example, you say the results is wrong but please show what output you are expecting.